# Run javascript jquery in razor page context

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a asp.net razor partial view which is used multiple times on one page.
In that partial view I have javascript in the $(document).ready() which I want to do some jQuery stuff on the content of the partial view.

```
<div class="someclass">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.someclass').dosomething();
    ));
</script>
```

So the problem is that $('.someclass') returns to much elements when this partial view is use multiple times on one page.
How can I achieve that $('.someclass') returns only the intended element?

The only solution I see is to generate a unique id for the element and use that in the jQuery selector. But I don't like generating id's for that.

Any other ideas for a solution?

Comment: Is the .someclass element you want to modify always in the same position, e.g. first, third, last etc?

Comment: It also depends on what is `dosomething()` doing.. Anyhow, you could add a data-attribute to the particular div, and use the value in the selector to get only that div..

Comment: You are class here so will obviously return all matching class. that's what it is for. but if you want to work on individual `.something` elements you can use jQuery each http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: First of all you should not include scripts in partial views when it is used more than once

Comment: @Mark, yeah, that's perhaps the way I need to start thinking of...

Comment: @Mark: if you turn your comment into an answer, I can make that the accepted answer :-). As I am working on a single page application, it is absolutely the best to abandon javascript from views (Well, you need at least 1 line to load your javascript app, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule you should not include scripts in partial views and it will create unexpected behaviors if the partial views are used/loaded more than once. Also, the inline scripts avoids them get cached by the browser. Though sometimes we feel lazy it always best practice to separate the scripts out of the views.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to use that class only for init and remove it after the initialization like this:

```
<div class="someclass initSomething">
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.initSomething').dosomething().removeClass('initSomething');
    ));
</script>
```

Comment: But if there are 2 of this partial views on the page, the first $('.initSomething') will still return 2 elements. Not what I want.

Comment: Whats the problem with 2 elements?

Comment: Doesn't feel good that the script of the first partial view handle both divs and the script of the second partial view will do nothing. But perhaps I have to live with that.

Comment: That leads to the conclusion that you have to find a solution for loading your script only once ;) in asp.net was something like a user script manager which did this.. but I don't know whats the solution in mvc